# Safety considerations for making an "activity centre" for a child

Tags: voltage, batteries, safety

Firstly, I am very new to electrics and electronics.

I would like to make an activity centre for my 18 month old child, with some physical toys (chains, blocks, etc), and some electrics (buttons, switches hooked up to lights). I was planning to run it off a 12v battery, but eventually it will have exposed contacts, e.g. to plug cables in to route power to different things.

Is 12v safe for kids to play with? What precautions should I take? If 12v is too much, what is considered "safe" for a child to play with?

The circuits will be simple electric circuits with no capacitors/step up/down, or anything fancy like that. Just some wiring and some resistors to limit voltage to lower voltage sections (e.g. LEDs). Later down the track I might add an Arduino or RasPi to make it more interactive.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a 9V battery and touch it to your tongue. Now imagine that a small child is doing the same with a high-current 12V battery instead.

Comment: Using custom devices for entertaining a young child seems like a very poor plan. There are a lot of design considerations for building a safe device: from *avoiding* exposed contacts to not burning your house down if one part fails. There are many more areas (many beyond EE) to consider when creating something intended for use by children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 3V battery (two AA cells) would be a much better choice.  You can use either incandescent bulbs or LEDs with a low forward voltage (e.g. 2.1v) and a series resistor.

Later you can switch to a 3.3V Arduino and won't have to modify your original circuitry.

The body has a minimum resistance of around 1 to 2 Kohms, and 3V across such is 1.5 to 3 mA, which is between "barely perceptible" and "painful sensation" according [to this paper](http://bme.ccny.cuny.edu/faculty/mbikson/BiksonMSafeVoltageReview.pdf) (see Table 2, page 9).  This table is for 60 Hz AC voltages; DC has less of an effect.  In any case, 3V is not at all dangerous.

This resistance can lower though if the skin is wet, so be sure your child's hands are dry when using the equipment.

Comment: Thanks, this is good information. I will check if the illumiated push-buttons will work off lower voltage (3v), and if not, will use LEDs instead. I will also skip the exposed component for a few years (as it is a future plan anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Buy toys designed by people that know how to design toys for children.   You might mean well, but choke hazards are probably much more likely to hurt your child than electronic hazards.

Comment: Thank you for the concern. I am planning on only using parts that are either non choking hazards, or properly secured (inside a box secured with screws). Additionally, as with most toys, it'll be a strictly under supervision activity.